# Authorize webhook calls into a CodeIgniter app?

Tags: codeigniter, authorization, webhooks

An external CRM webhook will occasionally call into my CI app to notify me of a data change so I can update the CI app's cache. What's the best way to make sure those calls into my app are from an authorized source?

I looked at options like Tank Auth and Ion Auth but they appear to be overkill for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off leaving this to the webserver, like adding http auth or ip restrictions.  However if you want to do it in CI, you could check the requesting host/domain or IP address as well.